# stuck with dpkg

Tags: updates, 13.04, dpkg, downloads

I am using ubuntu 13.04.I was installing a program and it had to download a file from the internet.It was a huge one.I waited for 30 minutes but nothing turned up.so I thought to let go and I closed the terminal.next time I open synaptic and I find it commanding meto run`sudo dpkg --configure`
when I do the same file download resumes.I am pretty sure that the file download does not complete as I have a very slow,frequently disconnecting net connection.so is there any way to stop this process and close the terminal SAFELY.so that i can open synaptic and install programs as usual.THANKS in advance.

Comment: restart your system?

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for description on how to safely abort an apt-get process:

[How to safely abort apt-get install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253925/how-to-safely-abort-apt-get-install)

Put simply, using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> should be exactly what you're looking for.